# Why won't the threads in the omp parallel section be divided on their sections?

Tags: c++, search, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I am trying to implement the ternary search algorithm using the pragma omp parallel from the OpenMP library. I am using recursion and here is what I have reached so far in my code implementation.

This is the search function:

```
int ternarySearch(int arr[], int size, int left, int right, int num)
{
    if (left < 0 || right > size - 1 || left > right){
        return -1;
    }
    else if (num == arr[left]){
        return left-1;
    }
    else if (num == arr[right]){
        return right-1;
    }
    else if (num < arr[left]){
        return ternarySearch(arr, size, left - 1, right, num);
    }
    else if (num > arr[left] && num < arr[right]){
        return ternarySearch(arr, size, left + 1, right - 1, num);
    }
    else if (num > arr[right]){
        return ternarySearch(arr, size, left, right + 1, num);
    }
}
```

And here is the part in the main function calling the ternarySearch function:

```
omp_set_num_threads(4);
    int quarter = size / 4;

    /*Using Recursion*/
    cout << endl << "Parallel Using Recursion: " << endl << endl;
    bool isFound = false;
    double paraRecStartTime = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel shared(isFound)
    {
        int id, start, end, left, right, result;

        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        start = id*quarter;
        end = start + quarter;
        left = (quarter / 3) + start;
        right = end - (quarter / 3);
        cout << id << endl;
        result = ternarySearch(arr, end, left, right, num);
        if(result != -1) {
            cout << "Found by thread " << id << " in index " << result << endl;
            isFound = true;
        }
    }


    double paraRecRunTime = omp_get_wtime() - paraRecStartTime;
    cout << "Ternary Search took  " << paraRecRunTime << " sec using 4 threads." << endl << endl;

    if (isFound == false) {
        cout << "Number does not exist in the array." << endl << endl;
    }
```

The problem is that in the output, all the threads find the element, while each thread is supposed to be given only a section of the array to search within using the ternary searching algorithm. Can someone help me know where did I go wrong?

Comment: you have quite some integer divisions in there. Did you make sure all the results are ok? e.g. what is the value of `left = (quarter / 3) + start;`?

Comment: For the 4 different threads (0,1,2,3) the different values for left are 16, 66, 116, 166. which are correct technically I guess  after I calculated them manually by hand to double check @tobi303

Answer (score 0):

Read further in the OpenMP standard and use tasks for this. They suit recursive problems much better than using nested parallelism.